# Are there multiple solutions to this system of (two) equations? How can I know?

Tags: systems-of-equations, constraints

I have two equations:
$$N_sc_s + p_s L =N_s \gamma^sw$$
and
$$\frac{(1+g)N_s c_s}{\gamma} + \frac{(1+h)p_s L}{(1+n)\gamma} = N_s \gamma^s w$$
Where the variables are $c_s, p_s$. Obviously One way for both these equations to be true is for:
$$ \tag{1} N_sc_s = \frac{(1+g)N_s c_s}{\gamma} \text{ and } p_s L = \frac{(1+h)p_s L}{(1+n)\gamma}$$
which can be solved. However would solving $(1)$ necessarily give me **the** solution, or could be there other solutions (intuitively, I'm thinking that it's possible that instead of having the equalities in $(1)$, perhaps one term is less than it's corresponding term and the other one greater...) In fact, I would guess that there are multiple solutions...

**However**... if I add two restrictions: that $c_s, p_s >0$, then I have no clue whether there would be multiple solutions or not...

Also, for completeness, $g,h,n >0 \text{ and } < 1$, $\gamma >1$, $L,N$ are some large, positive constants.

Thanks